# gremlin hangs with sigle node hbase,titan-all 0.4.4

Tags: cassandra, hbase, analytics, apache-zookeeper, titan

I have set up single node hadoop and hbase onto it. I also set up titan onto it. But as soon as I start gremlin and do TitanFactory.open(conf) , it hangs and nothing happens.

my titan-hbase.properties is as follows:

```
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.port=2181
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
```

my titan-hbase-es.properties is as follows:

```
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.port=2181
#storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

#storage.index.search.backend=elasticsearch
#storage.index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
#storage.index.search.client-only=true

storage.index.search.backend=elasticsearch
storage.index.search.directory=../db/es
storage.index.search.client-only=false
storage.index.search.local-mode=true
```

I used the following command in Gremlin after which it hanged:

```
g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-hbase-es.properties');
```

I search net for this problem, and found some solution but couldn't understand those. They were telling something about zookeeper parent problem and something /hbase-unsecure in hbase-site.xml. I nothing like /hbase-unsecure in hbase-site.xml.

All my hadoop ,hbase and titan files are in /usr/local under the names hadoop, hbase-0.94 and tital-all respectively.

I'm using hadoop 2.6.0 , hbase-0.94.27 and titan-all 0.4.4

THanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many people stuck at this stage and many times even Google group for Titan-Development don't answer queries, If there is no specific reason to use Hbase, I advice you to shift to Cassandra and continue your work.
GL & HF.